# Oracle SQL Select Current Timestamp without Timezone and 24hr Format

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a Oracle SQL statement where I have to get the current timestamp as one of the columns. But I dont require the Timezone which CURRENT_TIMESTAMP gives or the AM/PM given by LOCALTIMESTAMP.

I require the current timestamp in 24hr format without the timezone.

Is it possible to get that in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're mixing 2 concepts here: "datatype" and "date format mask".

- data type: LOCALTIMESTAMP returns datatype TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns datatype TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. TIMESTAMP is similar to DATE but has a higher precision. As usual... checking the docs is worth it.
- date format mask: determines how you display the date information. Americans can't read 24 hour format, the rest of the world is confused by AM/PM. Fortunately, you can decide how you want to display the date as explained in the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210).

If you just want to return the current date in 24 hour format you could do something like:

```
SELECT  
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as mydate,
  <other columns>
  FROM
  <table_name>
```

If you need the date to be more precise and you require fractional seconds then you can use SYSTIMESTAMP instead of DATE with a format mask 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF9'

Comment: Thank you... Understood the concept and worked as expected